# Find the inverse $f(x) = 2x^2-8x, x>2 $

Tags: calculus, inverse

$$ 2x^2-8x,  x>2 $$

What is the best way to solve this problem.

$$x =  2y^2-8y $$

$$x =  y (2y-8) $$ do I divide both sides by $y$ so as to solve for $y$? Help

Comment: How about solving the quadratic equation that you wrote?

Comment: I am finding the inverse; thus, I am solving for y.

Answer (score 6):

$y=2x^2-8x$

so

$\frac{y}{2}=x^2-4x=(x-2)^2-4$

so (since $x>2$)

$x=2+\sqrt{4+\frac{y}{2}}$

Comment: Can you do more steps?

Comment: @SkakaZulu I could but I think it is instructive if I let you try and work out the algebra. If you continue to have trouble feel free to ask.